# Site vue.js em produção não carrega arquivos complementares

Tags: vue.js, configuração, build

Tenho um projeto em Vue.js. Executei o

> npm run build

para gerar os arquivos que irão subir para o servidor de produção.

Porém quando abro o index.html o navegador não renderiza nada e executando o console temos que novegador não consegue localizar os arquivos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O navegador entende que os arquivos estão na raiz do diretório.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Falta alguma configuração no package.json que configure esse mapeamento na hora do build?

```
"name": "base",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
  "build": "vue-cli-service build",
  "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
}
```

Estou usando as configurações padrões do vue-cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esta executando o projeto via protocolo `file://`, o Vue CLI assume que seu aplicativo será implantado na raiz de um domínio, ex: https://dominio.com.br/

Segundo a [documentação do Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configuration-reference), você pode criar um [arquivo de configuração](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js) que sera carregado automaticamente pelo `@vue/cli-service`

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  // Opções ...
}
```

se estiver utilizando versões anteriores a 3.3 do CLI defina `baseUrl`

```
baseUrl: '/diretorio_do_projeto/'
```

para versão igual ou superior a 3.3 do CLI `baseUrl` foi descontinuado, defina `publicPath`

```
publicPath: '/diretorio_do_projeto/'
```

também podes verificar se esta rodando em produção ou não:

```
 publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/diretorio_producao/' : '/'
```

> Lembre-se de configurar corretamente antes de subir para o servidor de produção

#### Referências:

- [Configuration Reference](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configuration-reference)
- [vue.config.js](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js)